# How to load saved .cpuprofile file in Chrome developer tools CPU profile?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

There's a save button in the Chrome dev tools profiler, but no load button. How do you load a saved profile back into Chrome to view it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a "Load" button just under the list of profiles.

[image: "Load" button on the Profiles tab in Chrome DevTools]

Comment: Could you please update the answer? Chrome has changed a lot, for example there is no "Profiles" tab and the "Performance" tab doesn't seem to contain the Load button.

EDIT: there's an up-arrow button, to the right of the record button.

Comment: @MartinVysny In newest version of Chrome, the "Profiles" tab is hidden by default. To enable it, open dev tools and click on the 3 dots menu (on the right side of the settings wheel) -> More tools -> JavaScript Profiler. This will enable the "JS Profiler" tab from where you may record profiles or upload previously saved .cpuprofile files.

Comment: I tried this solution and I'm getting the following error in the console: "Can’t load file. Supported file extensions: `.heapsnapshot', '.heaptimeline', '.heapprofile`."

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative way to view .cpuprofile files:
http://jamie-wong.com/post/speedscope/

It provides an online and offline version. It works also for "bigger" files where the built in viewer of VS code ist struggeling.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Chrome, the "load profile" button is located here [image]