# How to view flamegraph .cpuprofile files

Tags: nsolid

I'm comparing the cpu profile on a couple of branches of my app, and I have downloaded the .cpuprofile files from the console. I'd like to compare them side-by-side but I'm not clear on how to open the saved files.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/thlorenz/flamegraph/issues/14#issuecomment-163788219) describes how to generate flamegraphs from `.cpuprofile` files.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

**Flamegraph**

Web version - http://thlorenz.com/flamegraph/web/

Source Code - https://github.com/thlorenz/flamegraph

You can provide a `.cpuprofile` file using `--inputtype cpuprofile`

**Chrome Dev Tools**

`.cpuprofile` files are Google CPU Profiler Binary Data Files, N|Solid Console offer download the profiling information in this format. This format can we readed by some perfomance tools, also can be viewed on Chrome Developer Tools.

Under "Profiles" tab you can click on the "Load" button and provide the `.cpuprofile` file.

There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774548/how-to-load-saved-cpuprofile-file-in-chrome-developer-tools-cpu-profile) with a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I am specifically interested in viewing them as a flamegraph. I'm not seeing how to do that in the Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Right!, Sorry for missunderstand. I updated the answer with links to Flamegraph tool

Comment: This no longer works due to https://github.com/thlorenz/flamegraph/issues/21 and the alternative 0x also does not work currently https://github.com/davidmarkclements/0x/issues/215

Answer (score 0):

[VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has an integrated visualizer that supports viewing JavaScript `.cpuprofile` and `.heapprofile` files.

It provides [the following views](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/profiling#_analyzing-a-profile):

- Table view
- Flame view
- Left-heavy view