# Can I view a flamegraph of Chrome profiling data?

Tags: javascript, profiling

Are there any tools for viewing a flamegraph of browser profiling data?

This question is similar and refers to some relevant tools but they no longer work with newer versions of Chrome's cpuprofile at least for a year now

[How to view flamegraph .cpuprofile files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801345/how-to-view-flamegraph-cpuprofile-files)

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/davidmarkclements/0x?

Comment: @AntonRusak yes, I created this issue to show that it did not work with Chrome profiler files https://github.com/davidmarkclements/0x/issues/215 (if I am missing something and it is possible with 0x let me know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website works with the performance tab Profiler-#####.json from Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit) of chrome

https://speedscope.app/

Blog post:
http://jamie-wong.com/post/speedscope/